# script working in jsfiddle and not in a static file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

the page being displayed as the "result" of this jsfiddle is working how it should:
http://jsfiddle.net/ej4j8/3/

however, when i attach this source to a page the code seems to break.. also, was wondering if anyone could explain how to make the function "calculateTotal" declared globally becuase on the jsfiddle my error console gives me "not referenced" whenever that function is called.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() 
 {

function calculateTotal()
{

    var boilerPrice = getBoilerSizePrice() + getBedroomSizePrice() + getBathroomSizePrice()  + getTankSizePrice() ;

    //display the result
        var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "total price £"+boilerPrice;

    var divobj2 = document.getElementById('premPrice');
    divobj2.style.display='block';
    divobj2.innerHTML = "Premium price £"+((boilerPrice/100)*120);

}



var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})





 //Property Type array

 var house_prices = new Array();
 house_prices["Semi"]=1029;
 house_prices["Detatched"]=1290;
 house_prices["Terrace"]=1100;
 house_prices["Flat"]=900;

 function getBoilerSizePrice()
{  
    var boilerSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["house"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            boilerSizePrice = house_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return boilerSizePrice;
}




 var tank_prices = new Array();
 tank_prices["Yes"]=500;
 tank_prices["YBR"]=890;
 tank_prices["No"]=0;


 function getTankSizePrice()
{  
    var tankSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["tank"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            tankSizePrice = tank_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return tankSizePrice;
}

 //bedroom number array 

 var bedroom_prices= new Array();
 bedroom_prices["Beds1"]=89;
 bedroom_prices["Beds2"]=94;
 bedroom_prices["Beds3"]=112;
 bedroom_prices["Beds4"]=145;
 bedroom_prices["Beds5"]=169;
 bedroom_prices["Beds6"]=178;



  function getBedroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bedroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bedroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bedroomSizePrice = bedroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bedroomSizePrice;
}

  //bathroom number array
 var bathroom_prices = new Array();
 bathroom_prices["One"]=119;
 bathroom_prices["Two"]=129;
 bathroom_prices["Three"]=140;



function getBathroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bathroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bathroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bathroomSizePrice = bathroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bathroomSizePrice;
}

calculateTotal();




/* ellement for hiding classes
$(".").hide();

*/
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <html>
    <form id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Getting A Quote Is Easy</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We'll give you a quote in a few easy steps</h3> <br/>
    <p>Just tell us which options are most similar to your home</p>
            <br/>        

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">What Type Of Home Do You Have</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

            <label >Type Of Property</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Semi" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Detatched" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Terrace" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Flat" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                    <br/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
            <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
            <br/>
            <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bathrooms Do You Have</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

            <label >Number of Bathrooms</label>
            <br/>
            <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="One" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Two" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Three" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>        


        </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Do You Have A Cylinder</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

         <label >Do You Have A Cylinder Tank</label>
         <br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="Yes" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="YBR" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes (but needs removing)</label><br/>
                    <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="No" onclick="calculateTotal()" />No</label><br/>
                    <br/>
        </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Packages Available</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <p>standard and premium system specs</p>
        <br/>
                    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="premPrice"></div>

            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Enter your details to a get a free survey</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 

/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background-color:#FFC926;
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), ;
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin:10% 0% 5%  15%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 10.33%;
    float:left;

    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console. Off the top of my head I would guess one of the IDs is not labeled properly or the HTML isn't forming right.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have the jQuery script tag closed and you also had an src attribute in your embedded script tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() 
 {

function calculateTotal()
{

    var boilerPrice = getBoilerSizePrice() + getBedroomSizePrice() + getBathroomSizePrice()  + getTankSizePrice() ;

    //display the result
        var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "total price £"+boilerPrice;

    var divobj2 = document.getElementById('premPrice');
    divobj2.style.display='block';
    divobj2.innerHTML = "Premium price £"+((boilerPrice/100)*120);

}



var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})





 //Property Type array

 var house_prices = new Array();
 house_prices["Semi"]=1029;
 house_prices["Detatched"]=1290;
 house_prices["Terrace"]=1100;
 house_prices["Flat"]=900;

 function getBoilerSizePrice()
{  
    var boilerSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["house"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            boilerSizePrice = house_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return boilerSizePrice;
}




 var tank_prices = new Array();
 tank_prices["Yes"]=500;
 tank_prices["YBR"]=890;
 tank_prices["No"]=0;


 function getTankSizePrice()
{  
    var tankSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["tank"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            tankSizePrice = tank_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return tankSizePrice;
}

 //bedroom number array 

 var bedroom_prices= new Array();
 bedroom_prices["Beds1"]=89;
 bedroom_prices["Beds2"]=94;
 bedroom_prices["Beds3"]=112;
 bedroom_prices["Beds4"]=145;
 bedroom_prices["Beds5"]=169;
 bedroom_prices["Beds6"]=178;



  function getBedroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bedroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bedroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bedroomSizePrice = bedroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bedroomSizePrice;
}

  //bathroom number array
 var bathroom_prices = new Array();
 bathroom_prices["One"]=119;
 bathroom_prices["Two"]=129;
 bathroom_prices["Three"]=140;



function getBathroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bathroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["boilerform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bathroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bathroomSizePrice = bathroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bathroomSizePrice;
}

calculateTotal();




/* ellement for hiding classes
$(".").hide();

*/
});
</script>

<html>
<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Getting A Quote Is Easy</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We'll give you a quote in a few easy steps</h3> <br/>
<p>Just tell us which options are most similar to your home</p>
        <br/>        

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">What Type Of Home Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Type Of Property</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Semi" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Detatched" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Terrace" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Flat" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bathrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="One" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Two" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Three" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>        


    </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do You Have A Cylinder</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

     <label >Do You Have A Cylinder Tank</label>
     <br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="Yes" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="YBR" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes (but needs removing)</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="No" onclick="calculateTotal()" />No</label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Packages Available</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

    <p>standard and premium system specs</p>
    <br/>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                <br/>
                <div id="premPrice"></div>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Enter your details to a get a free survey</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</html>

<style type="text/css"> 

/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background-color:#FFC926;
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), ;
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin:10% 0% 5%  15%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 10.33%;
    float:left;

    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using **script** tags properly.

1. You need to should close script tag.
2. Write your code in separate script block.

*Code*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//YourCode
</script>
```